# tableless CSS problem

Tags: html, tabular, css

In general I know how to use css but not advanced css 
So I need some help in order to start. Unfortunately I can't find any good and decent guide for tables without css and the part I want to do is very tricky. So here is what I want and what I've done so far.[image: Template]

The height is not fixed by the way so I want it flexible because the main text might be very long or very small

Here is what I've done so far

http://jsfiddle.net/VmnDj/1/

This doesn't seem to work properly though because the minimum height is where the main text is and it never includes the whole picture. Some part of the picture is out of the container. Please can you contribute on this and explain me why do you have to take each step? My purpose is to learn from this and not just the solution. If you need something more please let me know.
Thank you very much in advance

Comment: You might be better off just using tables for this... I know that's probably not what you want to hear, but this is a fairly complex layout. Also, which browsers are you trying to support?

Comment: Well surely it's not what I want to hear but since it's not a real project but a learn-by-doing example I'd prefer doing it that way. FF4,Chrome, Opera, Safari, AND IE 8,9

Comment: Ok - in that case, please post your HTML structure as well (ideally at http://jsfiddle.net/), and we'll all be able to figure out what's going on, and hopefully help more :)

Comment: @Stephen here is what I got so far http://jsfiddle.net/VmnDj/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/86FMw/

Notice that there is no fixed height and the box will grow when the main text is longer.

HTML

```
<div class="cartitem">
    <div class="left">
        <img src="http://images.pictureshunt.com/pics/p/pear-5428.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="toptext">
        top text top text top text
    </div>
    <p>
        text text text text<br/>
        text text text text  text text text text text text text text <br/>
        text text text text text text text text <br/>  
    </p>
    <div class="buttonbar">
        <button>click me</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.cartitem {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 80px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
}

.left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 80px;
}

.toptext {
    background: silver;
}

.buttonbar {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Yep <p> tag was all I needed after all :/ But why I can't really understand why <p> made all the difference?

Comment: I dont think p makes the difference. The difference according to me lies in your `float`. Float makes the element get unrelated to it's parent. I'm using `position:absolute` on the child element and `position:relative` on the parent. Then using `top,left,bottom:0` makes the child element as high as the parent and grow/shrink with it.

Answer (score -1):

That layout looks like it would formerly be used in frames.

Try this for the top right DIV:
set the code for Text2 to something like this:

```
p.tab {
  margin-top: -2em;
  margin-left: /* spacer_distance in em/px */;
}
```

I made 3 columns of text to mimic a table on some of my pages since the text displayed wasn't very wide in the first place.

Keep in mind we now deal with mobile device users. So only having 2 columns in that DIV should work. But, be wary spreading more text across that space without using min-width statements to the entire viewport.